# Powershell - Copy-Item : Invalid Signature

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to grab Security logs from a bunch of servers and put it in a shared folder in my shares. The script sometimes returns an error:

```
    Copy-Item : Invalid Signature.
At C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Copy.ps1:45 char:13
+             Copy-Item -Path $sourceUncPath -Destination $uniqueTargetPath -Verbo ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

This is my script:

```
$servers = @(

"SERVER1", 
"SERVER2", 
"SERVER3",
"SERVER4"

)

$emailmsg = ""

$sourcePath = "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx"

$sourceSharePath = $sourcePath.Replace(":", "$")

$targetPath = "\\myserver.com\Shares\folder\for\logs"

$targetName = $sourcePath.split('\')[-1]

$errors = ""

$servers | %{

    $date = get-date -Format MM.dd.yyyy_h.mm.stt

    $server = $_

    $sourceUncPath = "\\$server\$sourceSharePath"

    $uniqueTargetName = $targetName.Replace(".", "-$server-$date.")

    $uniqueTargetPath = "$targetPath\$uniqueTargetName"

    if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -Verbose) {

        if (Test-Path $sourceUncPath -Verbose) {

            Copy-Item -Path $sourceUncPath -Destination $uniqueTargetPath -Verbose

#            Clear-EventLog -LogName "Security" -ComputerName $server

        }
        else { $emailmsg += "Path to $server not found`n"}
    }
    else { $emailmsg += "$server Unreachable`n"}
}

$SMTPserver = "my.server.com"
$From = "my@email.com"
$Subject = "Security Log Report"
$Body = ("<html><body><h4><br><br>" + $emailmsg + "</h4></body></html></br></br>")

Send-MailMessage -Verbose -SmtpServer $SMTPserver -To "other@mail.com" -Subject $Subject -From $From -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml
```

Sometimes the script runs fine for couple server and fails for others and if I re-run, it might fail for the servers I previously successfully backed up.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Try `Copy-Item -Path $sourceUncPath -Destination $uniqueTargetPath -Verbose` without `-Path`

Comment: no dice, same issue

Comment: Sounds like a [SMB issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2686098) rather than a PowerShell issue.

Comment: there is anything else I can use other than Copy-Item?